# How to build angular for production with laravel?

Tags: php, angular, laravel

So i have a project that's using angular front end and laravel backend. The online server files only consist of laravel files and i've been told that i am supposed to build the front end files then transfer it to the laravel folder. How do i do that?

This is my folder structure.

[image]

The sourcecode folder contains angular files while website folder contains laravel files such as:

This is inside sourcecode folder.

[image]

This is inside website folder

[image]

The instructions given to me is

> To build code for production (your live site) after making changes, use  npm run build and gulp dist commands. This will compile, optimize and output all front-end code into public/client folder. To update your production site, copy (and override) public/client folder and resources/views/app.blade.php file.

I did that as well. I ran npm run build and gulp dist inside the sourcecode folder and terminal shows no errors. Everything went well. Inside the website folder, the public/client folder and the app.blade was updated as well based on the time last modified because it's auto modified just afteer i finished running the npm run build and gulp dist. However when i start the laravel localhost, the page wont load. When i ran php artisan serve and open the APP_URL that i set in the .env file, i get the error Hmm cant connect to page and in the console it says this crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue may be more related to the View architecture for Laravel, then Angular. For Angular, all that's happening, is a few files are being generated in dist/*, which you can literally just throw onto a webserver and that's the whole application.

The next piece is putting it somewhere your web server will find it, which may be related to the Laravel configuration.

My recommendation is to make sure the files are being generated in dist/* (or if the path is overridden, verify in the overridden area), and most importantly, verify that your app.blade.php file is even being called. If not, you can focus on that.

Maybe just put a "Hello world" style line into into the php file and make sure it's rendering first.

```
<?php
  phpinfo();
?>
```

Remember, Angular runs entirely within the browser, you just need to make the JS, CSS, and other files accessible, assuming they are actually being generated and moved into the correct location.